# Get files from selected folder in TYPO3 custom extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I have created a field to select the folder using Flexform in my custom extension. But I am unable to display all the files inside that folder. Does anyone know about this? Please help. Here is my code to add a field for selecting the folder in Flexform.

```xml
<settings.path>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>LLL:EXT:file_list/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_flexform.xlf:filelist.path</label>
        <config>
            <type>input</type>
            <renderType>inputLink</renderType>
            <size>48</size>
            <eval>trim</eval>
            <fieldControl>
                <linkPopup>
                    <options>
                        <blindLinkOptions>page,url,mail,spec,file,telephone</blindLinkOptions>
                        <blindLinkFields>class,target,title,params</blindLinkFields>
                    </options>
                </linkPopup>
            </fieldControl>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.path>
```

setup.typoscript:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:spt_gallerymanagement/Configuration/TypoScript/DataProcessors/Processors/FilesProcessor.typoscript">
plugin.tx_sptgallerymanagement_sptgallerymanagement {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:spt_gallerymanagement/Resources/Private/Templates/
        templateRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_sptgallerymanagement_sptgallerymanagement.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:spt_gallerymanagement/Resources/Private/Partials/
        partialRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_sptgallerymanagement_sptgallerymanagement.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:spt_gallerymanagement/Resources/Private/Layouts/
        layoutRootPaths.1 = {$plugin.tx_sptgallerymanagement_sptgallerymanagement.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_sptgallerymanagement_sptgallerymanagement.persistence.storagePid}
        #recursive = 1
    }
    features {
        #skipDefaultArguments = 1
        # if set to 1, the enable fields are ignored in BE context
        ignoreAllEnableFieldsInBe = 0
    }
    mvc {
        #callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
    }
}
# these classes are only used in auto-generated templates
plugin.tx_sptgallerymanagement._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE (
    textarea.f3-form-error {
        background-color:#FF9F9F;
        border: 1px #FF0000 solid;
    }
    input.f3-form-error {
        background-color:#FF9F9F;
        border: 1px #FF0000 solid;
    }
    .tx-spt-gallerymanagement table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border-spacing:10px;
    }
    .tx-spt-gallerymanagement table th {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .tx-spt-gallerymanagement table td {
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .typo3-messages .message-error {
        color:red;
    }
    .typo3-messages .message-ok {
        color:green;
    }
)
```

FilesProcessor.typoscript:

```
tt_content {
   examples_dataprocfiles =< lib.contentElement
   examples_dataprocfiles {
      templateName = Galleryview
      dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
      dataProcessing.10  {
         folders.data = settings.path
         sorting = title
         as = FileList
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: how do you try to read that folder and display the files? What output do you expect? what do you get?

Comment: I have more than 100 images in this folder. In my extension backend, I need only the option to select the folder but in the front end, I need to display all the images in this folder and the folder name too. when i use the above code i only get the path of the folder. Eg : t3://folder?storage=1&identifier=%2Ftest%2F

Comment: this typoscipt (found in the manual) is written for a content element (`CType`= `examples_dataprocfiles`). if you you use a plugin you need to [prepare your variables in your controller](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/View/Index.html).

Comment: it might be complicated if you need a typoscript rendering from PHP (in PHP you can read folders with PHP, but there is no metadata from `sys_file_metadata`). But you can do so. You even can call typoscript from FLUID: (use the [`cObject` ViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/11.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html))

Comment: Can you add your TYPO3 version?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a [`FilesProcessor`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.html?highlight=filesprocessor#confval-folders) in your FLUID.

just define your FLUID variable:

```
  :
  dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
  dataProcessing.10 { {
    folders.data = settings.path
    sorting = title
    as = FileList
  }
  :
```

Then you can use a partial to render that special FLUID variable.

**You might get inspired by the CE 'uploads'.** Therefore inspect `tt_content.uploads` in your TSOB (TypoScript-Object-Browser)

Comment: Can you give a detailed code, please? sorry, i am new in typo3.

Comment: more code depends on your definition and usage of your extension. Is it a new CE or a plugin? how do you do the rendering? the example code needs to be used where you prepare the data for your FLUID. Maybe you can use the default CE `uploads` with a nice filecollection based on your folder selection?

Comment: It is a plugin.

Comment: have you considered to use the `uploads`-CE? for all CEs you could change the rendering (in an own extension). It's easier to change a few FLUID templates than to create a complete new CE, which also include FLUID templates.